# joining 2 mysql tables duplicated

Tags: mysql

How do I join the two respective table below?

```
routing
routing_id |work_center_id |description |machine|UOM


routing_has_work_center 
routing_routing_id| work_center_work_center_id |production_hour
```

I tried this but it don't work

```
$queryRouting = "SELECT routing.*, routing_has_work_center.*
FROM routing, routing_has_work_center
WHERE routing_id.id = routing_routing.id";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query doesn't join the tables right now. This should do the trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM routing 
JOIN routing_has_work_center
ON routing.routing_id = routing_has_work_center.routing_routing_id
```

Some solid reference on MySQL joins that should help you understand them better: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/.

Comment: hi, there's a error stating  'Unknown column 'routing_id.id' in 'on clause'. Why??

Comment: Apologies, I mis-typed the first time I wrote out the query - I likely fixed it shortly after you tried it. When referencing a column in a database, it's formatted [database].[column]. "routing_id" is a column, so to reference it you use "routing.routing_id".

Comment: I tried this: $queryRouting = "SELECT *
FROM routing 
JOIN routing_has_work_center
ON routing.routing_id = routing_has_work_center.id"; but it says "Unknown column 'routing_has_work_center.id' in 'on clause'

Comment: Ah, I missed that your ID columns are not called "id" due to your query using them. It should be routing.routing_id and routing_has_work_center.routing_routing_id. Remember, [database].[column].